# problem of tensorflow1.10.0 debugger WARNING

Tags: python, tensorflow

When I run the `tfdbg` commmand, `run -f has_inf_or_nan`, I got a warning:

> WARNING:tensorflow:Failed to load partition graphs for device
>   /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 from disk.

As a fallback, the client graphs will be used. This may cause mismatches in device names.

This warning is given by: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/debug/lib/debug_data.py in 782-784 lines,

How can I resolve it?
I don't find other people who have the same question with me.